# Generating an ER Diagram from SQL CREATE TABLE statements

Tags: tools, database-diagrams

As I can't find any ER diagram feature built in with Apex, I want to create one with the SQL statements I executed in order to set up the tables in my Apex Workbench.

I found schemaSpy, which is capable of generating diagrams from many database architectures, but it can't connect to Apex. (AFAIK)

Most of the other tools I found are doing the opposite of what I want - they let you design your scheme in a nice user interface and generate the according SQL statements afterwards.

As it was mentioned in the comments (and in other questions on stackexchange), it's possible to connect to Oracle Apex through ODBC, generating a diagram with some tools, i.e. Microsoft Visio.

Maybe I have to do it this way, but I was curious, if it's possible even without an existing database scheme; just SQL.

Is there a free (better: open source) tool which analyzes given CREATE TABLE-statements, including foreign keys, to an entity relationship diagram?

Comment: As in Oracle APEX? There are plenty of apps that will connect to an Oracle database and generate ERDs from schemas

Comment: @Phil yes, Oracle Apex - if there is no tool like the one I'm looking for, I guess I have to do it this way.

Comment: Maybe this previous question on stackexchange helps you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14172/how-to-export-an-er-diagram-from-an-oracle-db

Comment: @GuidoLeenders thanks for the hint, maybe I have to do it this way. I was just curious, because I haven't found a tool for SQL->ER.

Comment: I can imagine. We've written our own. We extract datamodel into graphml and then use yEd to lay it out nicely.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders I thought of writing my own too - thanks for graphml and yEd, this could be useful :)

Comment: @swasheck I was looking for a free / open source tool. None of your suggestions match my criteria.

Comment: Visual paradigm can take sql create statements and generate an ERD, although it is a little limited (doesn't work with some foreign key syntax).  I used paradigm to create the ERD then took a screenshot.  If you export it, it has a watermark.  https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/reverse-ddl.jsp